# Security Exception on windows hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, hosting

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

My Code is:

```
            Mail.To.Add("123@abc.co.in");             
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            client.Port = 587;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("123@abc.co.in", "123");
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            string body = MailBody;
            var mail = Mail;
            MailAddress From = new MailAddress("123@abc.co.in", "Test Mail");
            mail.From = From;
            mail.Subject = MailSubject;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = body;
            client.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your web.config to allow `<trust Level="Medium" />` or `<trust Level="Full" />` - but this sounds like you should check your IIS config or contact your ISP (as they often block that).

Also, there are many posts discussing this error around the web.

Comment: I have tried both, <trust Level="Medium" /> and <trust Level="Full" />, but then new error appear as  "An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine".

Comment: @Partha Please make sure that your hosting provider support Full Trust. If not, it wont work.